# how to upgrade dotnetcore from version 1.0.4 to version 2.0.2 on centos?

Tags: .net-core, version, upgrade, centos7

how to upgrade .net-core from version 1.0.4 to version 2.0.2 on centos?
I have some asp.net core applications run on centos version 7.4.1708, now the version of dotnet is 1.0.4, so how to upgrade it to version 2.0.2? Thanks a lot!

Sorry, I got it, somehow  the Microsoft Product feed had been removed for mistake,  that's it.

Some pits or tips: generally, .net-core 1.0 will be installed at /opt/dotnet
and .net-core 2.0.0 will be installed at /usr/share/dotnet, so when you finish 
upgrade , you might wander why the result of command "dotnet --version" still is 1.0.4, you need unlink /usr/local/bin/dotnet and ln -s usr/share/dotnet/dotnet since /usr/local/bin is prior to /usr/bin by default.

If your applications were developed under .net-core 1.0, they don't work under 
.net-core 2.0.0, the error will be 
"It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:      /
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'"

Under .net-core version 2.0.2 circumstance, no aforementioned troublesome issue.

csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you provide csproj file?

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one SDK on your centOS.
If you try

```
/usr/bin/dotnet --version
```

command you will see the version is 2.0.2

you can solve the problem like this:

```
rm -f /usr/local/bin/dotnet
ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet
```